# How to compute the longest non-contiguous common sequence?

Tags: algorithm

`LongestCommonSequence[]` works well, but what about finding the longest common *sub-sequence* (not necessarily contiguous)? Is this function built in to the genome package? And it would really help me to know the big-o complexity for this function.

Comment: There is `LongestCommonSubsequence`. AFAIK, the complexity is `O(n^2)` in general. Perhaps, in some cases, when certain additional information about sequences is available, there exist faster algorithms.

Comment: The function `LongestIncreasingSubsequence` (in Combinatorica) is defined for a permutation as argument. But since you inquire about the genome package, this function will not be applicable.

Comment: `Combinatorica` can no longer be used

Comment: Without breaking all `Graph` functionality and a few other things...